# ERROR: must be owner of type character varying or type json

Tags: postgresql, casting, amazon-rds

I need to cast varchar to json using:

```
CREATE CAST (character varying AS json) WITHOUT FUNCTION as ASSIGNMENT;
```

Connecting to Postgres with the master account of my RDS Postgres instance, I get the following error

```
ERROR:  must be owner of type character varying or type json
```

The owner is rdsadmin:

```
\dT+ varchar                                                      
               List of data types
Schema   |       Name        | Internal name | Size | Elements |  Owner   | Access privileges |                            Description
------------+-------------------+---------------+------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 pg_catalog | character varying | varchar       | var  |          | rdsadmin |                   | varchar(length), non-blank-padded string, variable storage length
```

Now I don't have rdsadmin password, is there any other way to run this query?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can bootstrap your way to the full `rdsadmin` privileges.

However it seems that you can make yourself the owner of types:

`ALTER TYPE json OWNER TO myowner;`

And then you can create casts for that type to your heart's content.